# How to pass paramaters to a pipelineJob in DSL

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

I have very similar pipeline jobs that have only differences are parameters. The goal is to create these jobs by passing parameters in a DSL script without any code duplication.

I followed [this article](http://dev.to/jalogut/centralise-jenkins-pipelines-configuration-using-shared-libraries). So If you run the DSL script below after you implemented the steps as mentioned in the article, my script able to run.

TL;DR 
In that article adds a shared library and also have Jenkinsfile use that shared library.

I have a very similar approach. The difference is I want to create my build jobs via DSL and, changes default parameters of the Jenkinsfile by settings on the DSL.

The question is how can I pass/override parameters in the Jenkinsfile.

```
// BTW I'll run this code below in a loop. Open for any suggesstion 
pipelineJob('AwesomeBild') {

    description("A pipeline created by dsl")

    definition {
        cpsScm {
            scm {
                git {
                    remote { url('https://github.com/jalogut/jenkinsfile-shared-library-sample.git') }
                    branches('master')
                    // how can I pass params to the file
                    scriptPath('Jenkinsfile')
                    extensions { }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Parameters worked well. Here is the lastest version of the DSL file.

```
pipelineJob('AwesomeBild') {

    description("A pipeline created by dsl")


    parameters {
        stringParam( "key", "value" )
    }

    definition {
        cpsScm {
            scm {
                git {
                    remote { url('https://github.com/jalogut/jenkinsfile-shared-library-sample.git') }
                    branches('master')
                    // how can I pass params to the file
                    scriptPath('Jenkinsfile')
                    extensions { }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Environment variables ?

Comment: I tried that. It didn't work. Maybe I couldn't.

Comment: This shows how to pass parameters to pipeline with from the DSL jobwiththe dsl-created job:
https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/pipelineJob-parameters

Answer (score -1):

The solution is simple:
just use $key, but leave the single quotes:

```
scriptPath('Jenkinsfile$key')
```